# Loading all the Images from the file Qt

Tags: qt

I want to load all the images from the text file to widget in Qt.

I have written the code in this way,

```
void project::showfile()
{
    QString fileName = "/home/main/Desktop/image_file.txt";
    show_image(fileName); 
}

void project :: show_image(const QString &fileName)
{
    Widget *wid1=new Widget(ui->scrollArea_2);

    QFile file(fileName);
    qDebug()<<"test";

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error opening file";
    }

    QString line;
    QTextStream InputDataFile(&file);
    while(!InputDataFile.atEnd())
    {
        line = InputDataFile.readLine();

        QPixmap pixmap(line);
        wid1->setPixmap(line);

        wid1->resize(pixmap.size());
        wid1->show();
    }
    file.close();
}
```

For your example my `image_file.txt` contains

```
/home/keerthana/Desktop/images/2_222_31.jpg
```

While I am using this code I can load only the last image in the file. I want to load all the images to the GUI.

Can any one help me? That how can I load everything.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not complete, but the code seems to suggest you're loading the image repeatedly on the same widget. It seems correct that only the last is shown. Each pixmap you load seems to replace the previous...

Comment: ya you are rite, i am loading in the same widget,after that i have planned to use timer so that each interval of time it will load the image one by one.Now how can i print all the image .. can u please help me asap

Comment: Without replacing the older image , how can i load it. can you please explain me via my code. so it will be much helpful for me

Comment: If all you want to do is load in memory, just place your QPixmaps in a data structure like QList. Then when ou want to show, call the setPixmap method passing the specific QPixmap you want to show.

Comment: sorry to say ! I couldn't get your method , can you please explain me clearly sir..

Comment: Insert the QPixmap you load with the code you reported in a QList<QPixmap>. Do not call setPixmap. Then use a QTimer to call setPixmap with a different QPixmap.